# How to check json file is having a particular string

Tags: c#, json

```
"Myapplication": {        
        "RequestTimeoutAfterXHours": 24,
        "Settings": [
            {
                "Name": "app2
                "MetadataUrl": "{app2}/mine/.known/configuration",
                "ValidateIssuer": false
            }
        ]
    },
"application": {
    "app2": {
      "MetadataUrl": "{app2}/mine/.known/configuration",
      "ValidateIssuer": false
    }
  }
```

In the above Json i want to check MetadataUrl is there in Myapplication section or not. How to verify it. In some jsons it may not be there.

Comment: If it will never be in any other section, just string.Contains it

Comment: Its there in both sections in Myapplication and application so i want to check only in Myapplication its there or not.

Comment: Which json serializer are you using Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json or other?

Comment: i am using Newtonsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you can use LINQ against the `Settings` collection.

#### Query Syntax

```cs
var metaUrlCount =
    from setting in JObject.Parse(json)["Myapplication"]["Settings"]
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)setting["MetadataUrl"])
    select 1;

Console.WriteLine(metaUrlCount.Any());
```

#### Method Syntax

```cs
Console.WriteLine(
   JObject.Parse(json)["Myapplication"]["Settings"]
      .Any(setting => !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)setting["MetadataUrl"])));
```

Please bear in mind that indexer operator might return `null`, so you should check it before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it with `SelectToken`

```
var json = "json here";
            
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = jobj.SelectToken("$..Myapplication..MetadataUrl");
var tokenWithAnySettingsWithMetadataUrl = jobj.SelectToken("$..Myapplication.Settings[*].MetadataUrl");
var tokenWithFirstSettingsWithMetadataUrl = jobj.SelectToken("$..Myapplication.Settings[0].MetadataUrl");
Console.WriteLine($"path exist - {token != null}");
Console.WriteLine($"path with any settings exist - {tokenWithAnySettingsWithMetadataUrl != null}");
Console.WriteLine($"path with first settings exist - {tokenWithFirstSettingsWithMetadataUrl != null}");

//result:
//path exist - True
//path with any settings exist - True
//path with first settings exist - True
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6VwhD6

Comment: It is possible to add "Settings" in jobj.SelectToken("$..Myapplication..MetadataUrl")